# How to gracefully integrate unit testing where none is present?

Tags: unit-testing, standards, design-principles, principles

I have been tasked with developing a document for internal testing standards and procedures in our company. I've been doing plenty of research and found some good articles, but I always like to reach out to the community for input on here.

That being said, my question is this: How do you take a company that has a very large legacy code base that is barely testable, if at all testable, and try to test what you can efficiently? Do you have any tips on how to create some useful automated test cases for tightly coupled code?

All of our new code is being written to be as loosely coupled as possible, and we're all pretty proud of the direction we're going with new development. For the record, we're a Microsoft shop transitioning from VB to C# ASP.NET development.

Comment: See "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" by Michael C. Feathers.

Comment: My coworker actually has this book at his desk. I'll be reading it, thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: See [Implementing unit testing at a company that doesn't do it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/156277/247375) on Software Engineering SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two aspects to this question:  technical, and political.

The technical approach is quite well defined in Michael Feathers' book [Working Effectively With Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052).  Since you can't test the whole blob of code at once, you hack it apart along imaginary non-architectural "seams".  These would be logical chokepoints in the code, where a block of functionality seems like it is somewhat isolated from the rest of the code base.  This isn't necessarily the "best" architectural place to split it, it's all about selecting an isolated block of logic that can be tested on its own.  Split it into two modules at this point: the bulk of the code, and your isolated functions.  Now, add automated testing at that point to exercise the isolated functions.  This will prove that any changes you make to the logic won't have adverse effects on the bulk of the code.

Now you can go to town and refactor the isolated logic following the SOLID OO design principles, the DRY principle, etc.  [Martin Fowler's Refactoring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672) book is an excellent reference here.  As you refactor, add unit tests to the newly refactored classes and methods.  Try to stay "behind the line" you drew with the split you created; this will help prevent compatibility issues.

What you want to end up with is a well-structured set of fully unit tested logic that follows best OO design; this will attach to a temporary compatibility layer that hooks it up to the seam you cut earlier.  Repeat this process for other isolated sections of logic.  Then, you should be able to start joining them, and discarding the temporary layers.  Finally, you'll end up with a beautiful codebase.

Note in advance that this will take a long, long time.  And thus enters the politics.  Even if you convince your manager that improving the code base will enable you to make changes better/cheaper/faster, that viewpoint probably will not be shared by the executives above them.  What the executives see is that time spent refactoring code is time not spent on adding requested features.  And they're not wrong: what you and I may consider to be necessary maintenance is not where they want to spend their limited budgets.  In their minds, today's code works just fine even if it's expensive to maintain.  In other words, they're thinking "if it ain't broke, don't fix it."

You'll need to present to them a plan to get to a refactored code base.  This will include the approach, the steps involved, the big chunks of work you see, and an estimated time line.  Its also good to present alternatives here:  would you be better served by a full rewrite?  Should you change languages?  Should you move it to a service oriented architecture?  Should you move it into the cloud, and sell it as a hosted service?  All these are questions they should be considering at the top, even if they aren't thinking about them today.

If you do finally get them to agree, waste no time in upgrading your tools and setting up a modern development chain that includes practices such as peer code reviews and automated unit test execution, packaging, and deployment to QA.

Having personally barked up this tree for 11 years, I can only assure you it's incredibly not easy.  It requires a change all the way at the top of the tech ladder in your organization:  CIO, CTO, SVP of Development, or whoever.  You also have to convince your technical peers: you may have people who have a long history with the old product and who don't really want to change it.  They may even see your complaining about its current state as a personal attack on their skills as a coder, and may look to sabotage or sandbag your efforts.

I sincerely wish you nothing but good luck on your venture!

Comment: Perfect answer, my friend. Thanks!